# UWP Javascript WinRTError: TypeInitialization_Type_NoTypeAvailable

Tags: javascript, win-universal-app, winjs, windows-10-universal, winrt-component

When I enable `<UseDotNetNativeToolchain>true</UseDotNetNativeToolchain>` in *.jsproj file, then one of the Universal component throws this error, without much details.

> WinRTError: The text associated with this error code could not be found.
>   TypeInitialization_Type_NoTypeAvailable

I tried to enable DotNetNativeToolChain in universal component but nothing changes. Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please share out a snippet of the code that is throwing this error? I am assuming that the application works fine in the Debug mode (i.e. without the .NET Native tools enabled) - can you please confirm this as well?